# conky transparency not working

Tags: transparency, conky

i can't get transparency on conk. This is my code:

```
# -- Conky settings_by_giancarlo64 -- #
background yes
update_interval 1

cpu_avg_samples 2
net_avg_samples 2

override_utf8_locale yes

double_buffer yes
no_buffers yes

text_buffer_size 2048
imlib_cache_size 0

own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
own_window yes
own_window_type normal
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_argb_value 0


border_inner_margin 0
border_outer_margin 0

minimum_size 450 180
maximum_width 450

alignment tr
gap_x 0
gap_y 50

# -- Graphics settings -- #
draw_shades no
draw_outline no
draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders no


# -- Lua load -- #
lua_load ./1text.lua 
lua_draw_hook_pre draw_text

#at least one line (empty or not) after TEXT
TEXT
hi
```

I was looking for solution but nothing i found helped me. Most posts were about adding 
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_argb_value 0
But it doesn't work for me. 
I should also say that its not my theme, i just found it.
source: http://giancarlo64.deviantart.com/art/Deep-Blue-Conky-334583765
I don't if it is  important but i am using XFCE.

Answer (score 2):

What works in my case is

```
own_window yes                      # run conky in separate window (no flickering)
own_window_class Conky              # 'Conky' is default value
own_window_type override            # 'override' means not under control of window manager 
own_window_transparent yes          # enable transparency
```

Note that I do not use `own_window_argb_visual` or `own_window_argb_value 0` as you are doing. My `.conkyrc` works fine on 4 different machines (also on one where I am using XFCE, too)

I remember a friend however who had to change one of the settings to `own_window_type normal` but that means that conky is also minimized when you make a "Show Desktop" action. If you do not want this, set `own_window_type dock` but that in turn requires you to set `gap_x` and `gap_y` values to position your conky window.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting own_window_type to desktop